# Different whenever and server's timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

My server's timezone is set to IST. And all my jobs scheduled are delayed by 5 hrs 30 min (deviation from GMT). I have followed this thread https://github.com/javan/whenever/pull/239 and tried all relevant patches, but none of them worked for me. Which timezone does whenever pick for its jobs?

Comment: You can do that in this way 
`require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)`

`every :day, :at => Time.zone.parse('09:30am') do
  rake "leave_reminder:daily"
end` OR LIKE IN THIS WAY `every :day, :at => '09:30am', by_timezone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' do
  rake "leave_reminder:daily"
end`

Comment: @Vishal  I have already tried it. It doesn't seem to help. I have also tried other variations of it but none of them seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess your web server / rails server is different than system TZ (the one you'll when running `date` in the command line).

You might want to set both time zones to the same value.

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-tz-environment-variable/ for more info.